# Move semantics with 2d array in C++

Tags: c++, class, c++11, pointers, c++17

Can someone please explain me how to make move semantics with 2d array of floats in a right way? I tried something like that:

```
struct Matrix {
    Matrix& operator=(Matrix&& rhs) noexcept {
        if (this == &rhs) {
            return *this;
        }

        for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
            delete[] matrix[i];
        }

        delete[] matrix;
        matrix = rhs.matrix;

        for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
            matrix[i] = rhs.matrix[i];
            rhs.matrix[i] = nullptr;
        }

        rhs.matrix = nullptr;
        return *this;
    }

    ~Matrix() {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
            delete[] matrix[i];
        }

        delete[] matrix;
    }

    int rows;
    int cols;
    float** matrix;
};
```

but in a line `rhs.matrix = nullptr` matrix became nullptr and I don't know how to fix it.

I tried to just change pointers in inner arrays but outer pointer leave with no changes. But I think it is wrong way because programm logic became incorrect.

Comment: use a 1d vector as the underlying data structure.  then you get move for free since vector is moveable.

Comment: `std::swap(matrix,rhs.matrix);` will do the job.  (Swap the other two members as well) That's all you need to do.

Comment: @NathanOliver But I wanna know the problem of this method

Comment: Remove the loop after `matrix = rhs.matrix;`. The loop is setting all the pointers to null.

Comment: `float**` double raw pointers in current  C++?  You might want to read up on the [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines).  And yes arguably this is use of raw pointers in a datastructure but it would still be better to use `std::vector<float>` here so you cannot by accident get double ownership while implementing a copy constructor. (And you can use std::vector's move behavior for your move constructor)

Comment: You set `matrix` to point to the same array as `rhs.matrix`, so your loop that nulls out the pointers in the array pointed to by `rhs.matrix` also nulls out the pointers in the array pointed to by `matrix`, since they're the same array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think best way is does nothing.

- You don't need create structure to reply on heap.
- You can chosen where is your structure data is stored.
- I still not sure the meaning of "Move semantic" but I thought it's mean copy `value` from `address target` to `address destination` and then release ownership from `address target`. So `Move semantic` is very simple operation when you move pointer variable because `value` of pointer variable is only address that point to your data.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

template <typename T>
struct Matrix {

    using self_type = Matrix<T>;

    explicit Matrix(size_t in_w, size_t in_h) :
        w{ in_w },
        h{ in_h },
        content(in_w * in_h)
    {
    }

    Matrix(self_type&&) = delete;// disable move construct

    self_type& operator=(self_type&&) = delete; // disable move assignment
    
    T& operator()(size_t x, size_t y) const { // overload operator for access array like 2D array in c++23 you can overload operator[] with multiple arguments.
        return content[y * w + x];
    }

    const size_t w;
    const size_t h;
    mutable std::vector<T> content; //pointer to heap
};

template <typename T>
void fill_mat(const Matrix<T>& m){
    for(size_t j = 0; j < m.h; j++){
        for(size_t i = 0; i < m.w; i++){
            m(i, j) = j * m.w + i;
        }
    }
}

template <typename T>
void print_mat(const Matrix<T>& m){
    for(size_t j = 0; j < m.h; j++){
        for(size_t i = 0; i < m.w; i++){
            std::cout << std::setw(2) << m(i, j) << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

int main(){
   auto m = std::make_unique<Matrix<int>>(2, 3); // allocate on heap
   fill_mat(*m);
   auto n = std::move(m);//no error because I didn't move data
   print_mat(*n);
}
```

Comment: `mutable`? just provide 2 accessors, one const and one not const.

Comment: @Jarod42  to allow `fill_mat` mutate `content` in `const Matrix<T>&`

Comment: Allowing modification of `const` objects means that they are not `const`. Don’t do that.

Comment: @Pete Becker . Then, When we can use `mutable` ? For me `mutable` isn't issue thing but `const_cast` is real issue. I feel when we need to use `const_cast` mean our program design gone wrong.

Comment: `mutable` is for case when method is "logically" `const`, but cannot. Cache and mutex are examples of that.

Comment: @Jarod42 Sorry. I still don't understand why use `mutable` is wrong here. Can you show me the program error that came from `mutable` usage in data member?

Comment: Almost never. There’s probably a question and answer about that already. If not, ask!